# Missing taxonomy menu when custom post type has show_in_menu set

Tags: wordpress, menu, custom-post-type, custom-taxonomy

I crete a custom post type with a taxonomy and all works fine.
WordPress create a main menu:

```
MyCustomPost
   +----------> MyCustomPost
   +----------> Add New
   +----------> My Taxonomy
```

However, I like to create a my own menu, like this:

```
MyTitle
   +----------> MyCustomPost
   +----------> Add New
   +----------> My Taxonomy
```

So, I create a my own menu:

```
        $menu_main = add_menu_page( 'MyMenu', 'MyMenu', 'edit_posts', 'my_menu_key', array( $this, 'menu_main'), $icon_menu, 100 );
```

When register my custom post type I set `show_in_menu` with `my_menu_key`, and its works.

```
MyMenu
   +----------> MyCustomPost
```

The question is: where is taxonomy? and `Add New sub menu?
Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Nice trick with `show_in_menu`. But the taxonomy sub-menu is [built in a *hard-coded* manner](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.6/wp-admin/menu.php#L128) and `register_taxonomy` [doesn't take any parameter](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.6/wp-includes/taxonomy.php#L314) like that. Probably, the *Add New* submenu works the same way.

A workaround is to manipulate the `global $submenu`:

```
// PHP 5.3+ anonymous function
add_action( 'admin_init', function() {
    global $submenu; 
    $submenu['my_menu_key'][10] = $submenu['edit.php?post_type=YOUR-CPT-SLUG'][10];
    $submenu['my_menu_key'][15] = $submenu['edit.php?post_type=YOUR-CPT-SLUG'][15];
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of manipulating the $submenu global, you can accomplish this by using built-in WordPress functions for better future compatibility.

```
add_action('admin_menu', 'add_tax_menus');
function add_tax_menus() {
    $key = 'edit.php?post_type=CUSTOM_POST_TYPE_SLUG';
    add_submenu_page($key, 'My Page Title', 'My Menu Title', 'manage_categories', 'edit-tags.php?taxonomy=TAXONOMY_SLUG&post_type=CUSTOM_POST_TYPE_SLUG');
}
```